# How to prove that the surface area of ball $B(0,R)$ in $R^{n}$ is in proportion to $R^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, partial-differential-equations

In $R^2$, the circumference of a circle is $2\pi R$

In $R^3$, the surface area of a ball is $4\pi R^2$

And I wonder what about the surface are in higher dimension.

How to define it and is it in proportion to $R^{n-1}$(that is $S = kR^{n-1}$)

Comment: Yes it is - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area . More precisely it is $\frac{2\,\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}R^{n-1}$

Comment: @Henry Thank you so much and it is very useful and I wonder if it is the definition of area?

Comment: It is not a definition but an analytical calculation

Comment: @Henry I got it and I am confused that why the area of sphere is the differentiate of the volume, could you give me some hints?

Comment: You could regard the hyper-volume as built up with hyper-spherical shells of small constant thickness so each shell having volume approximately equal to hyper-surface area times thickness.  Then take the limit of volume divided by thickness as the thickness tends towards $0$ and you get the derivative of  hyper-volume being the hyper-surface area